# Angular input event unit testing

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have unit test case to test global filter function with input event in angular application. I'm not sure if this is an angular version problem or if I'm missing anything from the test case.

Environment : Angular CLI: 12.2.6 Node: 14.17.6

Here's the error;

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'nativeElement')
```

**Home.component.ts**

```
  filterGlobal(dt: any, event){
    dt.filterGlobal(event.target.value, 'contains')
  }
```

**Home.component.html**

```
<p-table class="filterTable" #dt [columns]="cols" [value]="cars">
    <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
        <div style="text-align: right">
            <i class="pi pi-search" style="margin:4px 4px 0 0"></i>
            <input type="text" class="globalFilter" pInputText size="50" placeholder="Global Filter" (input)="dt.filterGlobal($event.target.value, 'contains')" style="width:auto">
        </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns">
                {{col.header}}
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [ngSwitch]="col.field">
                <input *ngSwitchCase="'brand'" class="brandFilter" pInputText type="text" (input)="dt.filter($event.target.value, col.field, col.filterMatchMode)">
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                {{rowData[col.field]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

**Home.component.spec.ts**

```
it('should use global filter and show 1 items', fakeAsync(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomeComponent);
    app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    const globalFilter = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(".globalFilter"));
    globalFilter.nativeElement.value = "dsad231ff";
    globalFilter.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event("input"));
    tick(300);
    fixture.detectChanges();

    const tableEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css(".filterTable"));
    const bodyRows = tableEl.query(By.css('.p-datatable-tbody')).queryAll(By.css('tr'));
    expect(bodyRows.length).toEqual(1);
}));
```

I tried this as well, still it didn't work for me

```
it('should click Send button with fakeAsync', fakeAsync(() => {
  let buttonElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.globalFilter'));
    
  spyOn(component, 'globalFilter');
  //Trigger click event after spyOn
  buttonElement.triggerEventHandler('put', null);
    
  tick();
  expect(component.globalFilter).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```

ERROR:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'triggerEventHandler')
```

Appreciated if any help

Comment: Have you put the module required for `p-table` in the `imports` array of `TestBed.configureTestingModule`? Have you put all the directives (pTemplate) in the `declarations` array of the `TestBed.configureTestingModule`?

Comment: No, I did not add p-table @AliF50

Comment: I think you should add it. That's why you're getting cannot read property `nativeElement` of undefined because Angular does not know to how render `p-table` and its directives.

Comment: Is the test case looking good @AliF50 ?

Comment: I think the test looks good, yes.

Comment: There is not such thing as "p-table" to import , did you mean "table" ? @AliF50

Comment: I assume you're using PrimeNG's table so you need to import `TableModule` at the minimum in the `imports` array. Check out this StackBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tabledoc-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts where they have a table painted. Look at the Module, there are some modules in the `imports` array of the `app.module.ts` that you need to have in your `TestBed.configureTestingModule` as well or else Angular unit tests won't know how to paint those elements.

Comment: I'm getting this error after adding "TableModule" , TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'queryAll')
 @AliF50

Comment: Is this the right query to use within the test case, i provided the html file content above in the question?       const bodyRows = tableEl.query(By.css('.p-datatable-tbody')).queryAll(By.css('tr'));
      expect(bodyRows.length).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(1);

Comment: @AliF50 do you see any issues with the test case?

Comment: Try this instead. `buttonElement.triggerEventHandler('input', { target: { value: 'abc' }});` for your 2nd test case. `input` is the event and we need to mock the `$event` object with the 2nd argument.

Comment: I tried the below but getting this error " Cannot read properties of null (reading 'triggerEventHandler" .         @AliF50                                                                                                          
    `let buttonElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.globalFilter'));
      buttonElement.triggerEventHandler('$event', { target: { value: 'abc' }});
      spyOn(component, 'globalFilter');
      buttonElement.triggerEventHandler('put', null);
      tick();
      expect(component.globalFilter).toHaveBeenCalled();`

Comment: It seems like that element is not in the DOM or HTML. I am not sure, sorry.

Comment: @AliF50 Could you check my below answer ?

Answer (score 0):

```
it('input event function with fakeAsync', fakeAsync(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HomeComponent);
      const component = TestBed.get(HomeComponent);
      spyOn(component, 'filterGlobal');
      component.filterGlobal('$event', { target: { value: 'contains' }});
      fixture.detectChanges();
      tick();
    
      expect(component.filterGlobal).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));
```

Comment: @AliF50 the above is not generating any error but it's not showing as covered in the code coverage report. Any advice on this ?

Comment: Do you have any thoughts on this @pop  @Brandon?

Comment: When you `spyOn` on line 3, you're removing the implementation details of the method. Change `spyOn` to `spyOn(component, 'filterGlobal').and.callThrough();`. The `.and.callThrough()` will call the function (not lose implementation details) but you will have another error. The first argument `$event` should be `{ filterGlobal: (arg1, arg2) => null }`. That being said, this test is not that great. We spOn a method that will be called, we explicitly call it in the unit test, and then we expect for it to be called.